# A função não adiciona á lista

Tags: c++

ESTA É A SOURCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gestor.h"
using namespace std;


int menu()
{ 
int opc;


    cout << "Faca a sua escolha!" << endl;
    cout << "1-> inserir avaria!" << endl;
    cout << "2-> listar avaria!" << endl;
    cout << "0-> sair" << endl;
    cin >> opc;

    return opc;


    }
    gestor *criargestor()
    {
    gestor*g;
    g = new gestor();
   return g;

}

void destruirgestor(gestor*g)
{
delete g;
}


void main()
{
   gestor *g;
   g = criargestor();
int opcao;

do
{   
    opcao = menu();

    switch (opcao)
    {
    case 1: g->addavaria();
        break;
    case 2:g->listaravarias();
        break;
    case 0:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "invalido!\n" << endl;
    }
} while (opcao!= 0);
destruirgestor(g);
}
```

ESTE E O HEADER FILE avaria.h

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>
using namespace std;
class avaria
{
int codigoavaria;
string nome;
string descricao;
public:
avaria(void);
avaria(int cod,string nm,string des);
void mostrar();
~avaria();
};
```

ESTE É O AVARIA.CPP

```
#include "avaria.h"

 avaria::avaria(void)// construtor da função vai inicializar as variáveis.
 {
cout << " passei na função= [" << __FUNCTION__ << "]" << endl;
}
avaria::avaria(int cod, string nm,string des) 
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
cout << " passei na função= [" << __FUNCTION__ << "]" << endl;
codigoavaria = cod;
nome =nm;
descricao = des;

}
void avaria::mostrar()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
cout << " passei na função= [" << __FUNCTION__ << "]" << endl;
cout << " codigo =" << codigoavaria << endl;
cout << "nome =" << "[" << nome << "]" << endl;
cout << "descrição" << "[" << descricao << "]" << endl;

}

avaria::~avaria()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
cout << " passei na função= [" << __FUNCTION__ << "]" << endl;
}
```

ESTE É O GESTOR.H

#pragma once
   #include
   #include
   #include"avaria.h"
   class gestor
   {
    list lav;

```
public:
gestor();
void addavaria();
void listaravarias();
~gestor();
};
```

ESTE É O GESTOR.CPP

```
#include "gestor.h"


gestor::gestor()
{

}

 void gestor::addavaria()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");


string descricao;
string nome;
int tipo;
avaria*av = NULL;

cout << "Introduza o tipo de avaria! (1) electrica (2) mecanica" <<         endl;
    cin >> tipo;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << " Introduza o nome da avaria!" << endl;
    getline(cin, nome);
    cout << "Introduza a descrição da avaria!" << endl;
    getline(cin,descricao);
    av = new avaria (tipo,nome,descricao);


}
 void gestor::listaravarias()
{
cout << "N. de Elementos da Lista = " << lav.size() << endl;
for (list<avaria*>::iterator Iter = lav.begin();
    Iter != lav.end(); Iter++)
{
    cout << "................................." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    (*Iter)->mostrar();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "..................................." << endl;
}
}


gestor::~gestor()
{
}
```

O que se passa é o seguinte a função addavaria() não parece estar a adiciona nenhuma avaria á lista, cada vez que compilo adiciono uma avaria e logo a seguir faço mostrar e a função diz que estão zero elementos adicionados á lista.
o programa é em c++ e está a funcionar com uma classe gestor (não tem hierarquia) que tem como função gerir todas as avarias da classe avaria.

Comment: se precisarem de algumas imagens que não estejam visiveis digam me

Comment: Não coloque imagens com código, coloque o código.

Comment: posso lhe mandar o meu programa por email?

Comment: Não, coloque o código que dê para vermos o erro e nada mais que isto. Se isto não for possível, a pergunta não pode ser feita aqui.

Comment: e bastante codigo e não consigo organizar a pergunta, com os cpps separados dos .hs

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: edições foram feitas ;)

Comment: Pelo que entendi voce cria o objeto avaria e não adiciona ele na lista da classe gestor. Só precisa adicionar na lista.

Comment: Como e que faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Em `gestor::addavaria()`, `av` não está sendo adicionado à lista, ou seja, tá faltando um `lav.push_back(av)`.